# How to modify Scipy's SVM classification rules?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I have been exploring Scikit-learn as a tool, and I am very interested in learning if I can modify how Scikit-learn classifies a data point, more specifically, its SVM function. I am looking for a programmatic way to attack this problem.

In general, we can say that SVM classification looks something like this, and let's imagine the blue points are positive, and red points are negative:
[SVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAhAR.jpg)

Where the classification occurs as follows:
[SVM Classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USsNV.jpg)

As my understanding goes, Scikit-learn does this for us quite easily.
However, I was wondering if there are any parameters I could change to make it look something more like this:
[SVM The way I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUlXw.jpg)

That is, the positive point that makes the support vector is also my decision boundary.. Is there another algorithm that I am missing? Would I have to build my SVM function from the ground up?

Thank you

Comment: [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/) doesn't have SVM.  Are you thinking of [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html)?

Comment: Absolutely, sorry for the big mistake. @WarrenWeckesser